# Optimized query to match and exclude multiple ManyToMany entries

Tags: python, django, django-models, query-optimization

I'm working on a tagging system that requires querying objects that have multiple tags as well as being able to exclude objects that have tags. The code below is a simple example of the queries I'm making. In reality there is an arbitrary number of tags that will be matched/excluded. My current implementation works but is slow over large amounts of data. I'm looking for a way to speed up this query.

```
class Model(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

Model.objects.filter(tags=tag_1).filter(tags=tag_2).exclude(tags=tag_3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already identified that line as culprit with the help e.g. of django-debug-toolbar I'd try two things:

- Filter using in instead of different clauses

  `Models.objects.filter(tags__in=[tag_1, tag_2])`
- Filter using ids instead of object

  `Model.objects.filter(tags__id=tag_1.id).filter(tags__id=tag_2.id)`

You can even combine the two.